# Updating double nested object in MongoDB with pymongo

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following object in MongoDB:

```json
{
   "_id":"...",
   "username":"XXX",
   "keys":[
      {
         "key":"c443c2cc2754d3",
         "ref":"Autos",
         "lists":[
            {
               "list_name":"Toyota",
               "key":"c443c2cc2754d3",
               "broken_parts":{
                  "headlights":false,
                  "bonnet":true,
                  "interior":{
                     "dashboard":true,
                     "electronics":false
                  }
               },
               "timestamp":"2023-01-26T13:00:21.803Z",
               "status":"parked"
            },
            {
               "list_name":"Nissan",
               "key":"c443c2cc2754d3",
               "broken_parts":{
                  "headlights":true,
                  "bonnet":false,
                  "interior":{
                     "dashboard":false,
                     "electronics":true
                  }
               },
               "timestamp":"2023-01-26T13:00:21.803Z",
               "status":"garage"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "key":"80d54bd834ff60",
         "ref":"Trucks",
         "lists":[
            {
               "list_name":"MAN",
               "key":"c443c2cc2754d3",
               "broken_parts":{
                  "headlights":false,
                  "bonnet":false,
                  "interior":{
                     "dashboard":false,
                     "electronics":false
                  }
               },
               "timestamp":"2023-01-26T13:00:21.803Z",
               "status":"parked"
            },
            {
               "list_name":"Toyota",
               "key":"c443c2cc2754d3",
               "broken_parts":{
                  "headlights":true,
                  "bonnet":false,
                  "interior":{
                     "dashboard":true,
                     "electronics":true
                  }
               },
               "timestamp":"2023-01-26T13:00:21.803Z",
               "status":"leased"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and whenever I try to update the status of an item inside a list, it only updates the first object.

If I try to update the status of the 1st list, 2nd object, it will only update the first one:

```py
self.users.update_one({"username": username,
                       "keys.key": key,
                       "keys.lists.list_name": listid
                      },
                      {"$set": {
                           "keys.0.lists.$.status": 'repaired'
                         }
                      }
                     )
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I update the list item I want? or even the 3rd nested object (dashboard, electronics)?

Comment: You are setting `keys.0`

Comment: In the example document, is it normal/accurate that all `keys.lists.key` are identical?